# How can I exclude a shadowJar during a Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, spring-cloud-connectors

I'm using `spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar` in a project, which is built with the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0` files as a shadow JAR (i.e. the files are included within the `spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector` JAR rather than just being a dependency.

The problem is, `jackson-databind` 2.10.0 now has known security problems but there is no later version of the Spring library with patched Jackson files. So, what I need to do is use the existing Spring library but newer Jackson libraries. If it were a normal dependency it would be easy enough, but obviously the files can't be removed from the Spring library.

So, it there any way of forcing Maven to ignore the embedded Jackson classes and only use the newer Jackson library (which is already included in my main project).

The Gradle build file (and the rest of the Spring project) can be found here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector/build.gradle

Comment: Simple answer to this: No (This is big issue with shaded jars which contain other dependencies) That blocks all options you have...

Comment: @khmarbaise - That's what I feared.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but the long-term solution to avoid this Jackson shading problem is to migrate from Spring Cloud Connectors to Java CFEnv. In many cases with Spring Boot apps, CFEnv is a drop-in replacement for Connectors (just changing dependencies in your build file). https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv#dependency-info

Answer (score 1):

You can construct your own patched version of the JAR by manually removing the `jackson-databind` files. Then you can use a new version number like `2.0.7.RELEASE-patched`.

Put this into your Nexus/Artifactory, or otherwise the local repository.